# Hybrid vector/list container?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm in need of a container that has the properties of both a vector and a list. I need fast random access to elements within the container, but I also need to be able to remove elements in the middle of the container without moving the other elements. I also need to be able to iterate over all elements in the container, and see at a glance (without iteration) how many elements are in the container.

After some thought, I've figured out how I could create such a container, using a vector as the base container, and wrapping the actual stored data within a struct that also contained fields to record whether the element was valid, and pointers to the next/previous valid element in the vector. Combined with some overloading and such, it sounds like it should be fairly transparent and fulfill my requirements.

But before I actually work on creating yet another container, I'm curious if anyone knows of an existing library that implements this very thing? I'd rather use something that works than spend time debugging a custom implementation. I've looked through the Boost library (which I'm already using), but haven't found this in there.

Comment: So if I insert 1 million elements, then I remove elements 1-499999, then I remove 500001-999998, then I remove element 500000...  What is left should be collection[0] and collection[1]?  Or should be it collection[0] and collection[999999]?  Also, when you iterate through the collection, do the elements have to come back in the order you added them?

Comment: It would be collection[0] and collection[999999]. I use the index of an element to refer to that particular element (hence the need for random access), so I don't want that index changing on me. And I don't care what order I iterate over the list, so long as I only have to touch valid elements.

Comment: What do you want this data structure *for*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the order does not matter, I would just use a hash table mapping integers to pointers.  `std::tr1::unordered_map<int, T *>` (or `std::unordered_map<int, unique_ptr<T>>` if C++0x is OK).

The hash table's elements can move around which is why you need to use a pointer, but it will support very fast insertion / lookup / deletion.  Iteration is fast too, but the elements will come out in an indeterminate order.

Alternatively, I think you can implement your own idea as a very simple combination of a `std::vector` and a `std::list`.  Just maintain both a `list<T> my_list` and a `vector<list<T>::iterator> my_vector`.  To add an object, push it onto the back of `my_list` and then push its iterator onto `my_vector`.  (Set an iterator to `my_list.end()` and decrement it to get the iterator for the last element.)  To lookup, look up in the vector and just dereference the iterator.  To delete, remove from the list (which you can do by iterator) and set the location in the vector to `my_list.end()`.

`std::list` guarantees the elements within will not move when you delete them.

[update]

I am feeling motivated.  First pass at an implementation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
class NairouList {
public:
  typedef std::list<T> list_t;
  typedef typename list_t::iterator iterator;
  typedef std::vector<iterator> vector_t;

  NairouList() : my_size(0)
  { }

  void push_back(const T &elt) {
      my_list.push_back(elt);
      iterator i = my_list.end();
      --i;
      my_vector.push_back(i);
      ++my_size;
  }

  T &operator[](typename vector_t::size_type n) {
      if (my_vector[n] == my_list.end())
          throw "Dave's not here, man";
      return *(my_vector[n]);
  }

  void remove(typename vector_t::size_type n) {
      my_list.erase(my_vector[n]);
      my_vector[n] = my_list.end();
      --my_size;
  }

  size_t size() const {
      return my_size;
  }

  iterator begin() {
      return my_list.begin();
  }

  iterator end() {
      return my_list.end();
  }

private:
  list_t my_list;
  vector_t my_vector;
  size_t my_size;
};
```

It is missing some Quality of Implementation touches...  Like, you probably want more error checking (what if I delete the same element twice?) and maybe some `const` versions of `operator[]`, `begin()`, `end()`.  But it's a start.

That said, for "a few thousand" elements a map will likely serve at least as well.  A good rule of thumb is "Never optimize anything until your profiler tells you to".

Comment: I used to use a map, but as frequently as I access elements in the container, I became concerned with the map's need to perform a search to find the element each time I wanted to use it (especially when I have thousands of elements in the map), rather than directly accessing the element as a vector would. However, I really like your second idea! I'll have to think that one over a bit.

Comment: `unordered_map` is usually faster than `map`.  Much, much faster.

Comment: Memory-footprint is the trade-off for the speed.

Comment: @Nairou: thousands of elements rarely stresses a map... even with a million on average it needs to compare the key to around 20 nodes before it finds a match. This can be very fast, especially if the map's sorted first on a simple type like an `int` or `double` that's rarely or never the same (the key might contain other discriminatory fields thereafter). Even strings that dont' share long common prefixes can be compared quickly. Still, `map` lookups can hit more memory pages than a hash map. You really should use a profiler before investing time in changing your implementation.

Comment: All very good points, thanks. Coming from a background in assembly language, I automatically cringe when forcing the CPU to repeatedly search for something I could otherwise locate more directly. But yes, this is premature optimization and may not be worth the investment. I will need to look more into unordered_map.

Comment: @Nemo: *hum*... Let's say I have `NairouList nairou = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};`. Then `nairou.remove(3); assert(nairou[3] == 4);` should pass (from the requirements), but in your case I would be hitting a "deleted" iterator instead.

Comment: @Matthieu:  Read my comment and the questioner's response on the original question.  This is the behavior he asked for...

Comment: @Nemo: Ah right! So in fact the OP does not want random access, but quick look-up by key...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you might be wanting a [std::deque](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/). Removing an element is not as efficient as a `std::list`, but because deque's are typically created by using non-contiguous memory "blocks" that are managed via an additional pointer array/vector internal to the container (each "block" would be an array of N elements), removal of an element inside of a `deque` does not cause the same re-shuffling operation that you would see with a vector.

**Edit:** On second though, and after reviewing some of the comments, while I think a `std::deque` could work, I think a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` will actually be better for you since it will allow the array-syntax indexing you want, yet give you fast removal of elements as well.

Comment: Does not allow efficient removal of elements in the middle.

Comment: std::deque is nice, but it doesn't very well handle removal of elements from the middle of the container. And performing that removal would change the indices for all elements that come after the point of removal.

Comment: Yes, the invalidation of pointers is a downside, but again, you should end-up avoiding the complexity that would be associated with the removal of an object from the middle of a std::vector. So removal is faster than a vector, but not as fast as a linked-list.

Comment: Hence the need for a hybrid. For my needs, my list is constantly having items added to it and older items removed from it. In that respect, a std::list would be perfect, except I need direct access to those items in the list without the need to iterate and find it first. Like a vector, I need to store an item, and immediately know it's index location (which is used as the ID for that item).

Comment: What's wrong with a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` then?  Make the key to the map the ID-value.  You should then get the best of both-words with fast access by ID-value, and fairly efficient removal.

Comment: @Jason, he said fast random access

Comment: @Daniel: BST's and hash-tables should qualify for fast random access, especially a hash-table ... and depending on the size of the map and the type being stored in the map, the look-up in the BST could be faster than the time it takes to hash a key-value (especially if your hash is not very good and creates a lot of collisions which can happen for more complicated class-types).